# For each row in a table, mark a group of columns as unique or not

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For a given table, I want to check if a group of columns together are unique or not. If so, I'd like to mark that row as TRUE, else mark it as False.

I know I can get aggregate numbers for how many unique, but I'd like to get it in the form of a column of TRUE / FALSE in a single column. With each row corresponding to the original table.

I'm trying to get this to work in BigQuery, but I'm also curious about a method in general for this.

**Sample Input:**

Check if in each row, the combination of [Fruits, Color] is unique. 
(The weight table is there just to illustrate that there could be unrelated columns in the table)

| Fruits | Color | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red | 1.1 |
| Apple | Green | 2.3 |
| Banana | Yellow | 4.4 |
| Banana | Yellow | 5.6 |

**Sample Output:**

| Result. |
| --- |
| True |
| True |
| False |
| False |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function

```
Select *
  , case when uniq_test = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end as result
From (
    Select *
      , count(*) over(partition by fruits, color) as uniq_test
    From your_table 
) d
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 1 = count(*) over Fruits_Color as Result
from your_table 
window Fruits_Color as (partition by Fruits, Color)
```

with output

[image]